# Is react-native-onesignal avaiable for Google Analytics for Firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-analytics, onesignal

I want setup Google Analytics for Firebase for my react-native project like:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/google-analytics-for-firebase
But seem react-native-onesignal not integrated. it is only avaiable in native:

IOS: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Source/OneSignalTrackFirebaseAnalytics.m
android : https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/src/main/java/com/onesignal/TrackFirebaseAnalytics.java
Anyone can help me or confirm this?

Comment: You would have  to just enable it in the console https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/google-analytics-for-firebase

Comment: i see in this lib: react-native-onesignal don't have os_notification_opened,os_notification_received, or os_notification_influence_open like native libary.

Comment: There are event listeners in react-native as well https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk#section-handling-notifications

Comment: thanks bro. I have successfully installed. but one more question: it just work at debug mode? and not work at release mode? Because i see docs, it configuration in debug view on firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneSignal will automatically send notification events to your analytics dashboard if Google Analytics for Firebase is correctly implemented.

Check out our [docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/google-analytics-for-firebase) on how to integrate with Google Analytics.

Comment: It's working fine in expo development client but not in release build.